# Convert a Winform user control to WPF user control

Tags: wpf, windows, user-controls

I have a project with a lot of User Controls developed in Windows Forms. All the controls are drawn in the UserControl_Paint() function. I would like to take the advantage of WPF vector graphics and the ability to draw complex graphics with ease. I need help in getting started. I have been studying and practicing a lot examples in Expression Design, Expression Blend, and WPF. But I can't take off the ground yet. As an example, I have the following Win Forms User Control, https://picasaweb.google.com/Jcarter121212/May202013?authkey=Gv1sRgCIuoi6eo6a2mMg#5880047219565280370

The above user control has used Windows Forms Hatch Brush for border and two rectangular controls, one to represent empty and another to represent level of liquid. It animates the liquid based on a property value that changes between 0 <-> 15 Ft.

This control will stretch and scale when put it on a Windows Form. How to do the same in WPF?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/25ceda82-306f-4716-a04a-3f206cef1e2c

Comment: Hob, I am aware of that. I would using ElementHost to embed WPF control. My question is how to draw the WPF control that can scale and stretch when I re-size the WPF control on Windows Form and with the appearance and functionality of the existing windows user control shown in the above link. Thanks